# Working with data that has different intervals/lags for linear regression

Tags: r, linear-regression, scatter-plot

I am working with satellite data and comparing two variables to make a linear regression. The Y variable has a 3-day lag whilst the X variable has a 5-day lag when the scatterplot is created it mostly shows it empty with the data laid out at random and not all points are being represented. Can the problem be the data that has different lags? I have attached a code that I have been using. Can you kindly assist.

[image]

```
# Install and load necessary libraries
install.packages("readr")  # For reading CSV data
install.packages("ggplot2")  # For visualization
install.packages("lmtest")  # For regression analysis
library(readr)
library(ggplot2)
library(lmtest)


data <- read.csv("C:/Users/WINDOWS 10/Desktop/desktop/Masters Doc/Results/R/SCL KNDVI and Soil moisture.csv")

# Remove rows with missing values
data <- na.omit(data)

# Summary statistics
summary (data)

# Scatter plot
ggplot(data, aes(x = SCLKNDVI, y = SCLSoil.moisture)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = " SCLKNDVI", y = "SCLSoil.moisture") +
  ggtitle("Scatter Plot of SCLKNDVI vs. Soil Moisture")

# Perform linear regression
regression_model<- lm(SCLSoil.moisture ~ SCLKNDVI, data = data)

# Summary of the regression model
summary(regression_model)

# Scatter plot with regression line
# Scatter plot
ggplot(data, aes(x =SCLKNDVI , y =  SCLSoil.moisture)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = "SCLKNDVI", y = "SCLSoil.Moisture") +
  ggtitle("Scatter Plot of KNDVI vs. Soil Moisture")
```

[Link to the table](https://eu.docworkspace.com/d/sIBD1zKqRAcSWsKoG)

I tried performing the NA omit data it worked but what if I am working with data that has many lags will it not skew the results of the linear regression. I was expecting graph with most of the points of the data used to show within the scatter plot.